# Помогите настроить Intelij idea 2016.2

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

Хочу что бы при создании проекта например Spring MVC он по умолчанию (шаблону) создавал необходимые пакеты, конфиг. файлы, и прочее.

Answer (score 1):

@Михаил Верламов Добрый день.
 Возможно вам подойдёт этот вариант http://www.nakov.com/blog/2016/08/05/creating-a-blog-system-with-spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jpa-and-mysql/

Comment: здесь принято давать **полный** ответ, а ссылки приводить лишь в качестве дополнения/иллюстрации.